# VSCode editor - Restart NodeJs server when file is changed

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code as my editor for NodeJS project.

Currently I need to manually restart server when I change files in my project.

Is there any plugin or configuration change in VSCode that can restart NodeJS server automatically when I make change in files.

Comment: Run your script with [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) instead of `node`.

Comment: Neither `nodemon` nor `node-dev` will work with VSCode. Once it kills the process, the debugger thinks it dead and turns off.

Comment: Looks like there's a feature request: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2103

Comment: Thanks, I subscribed to that issues to get notifications.

Comment: The issue  github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2103 already closed, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 30):

You can now use [Nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) with VS Code to achieve this. I tested the [Nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) support for VS Code today and it worked well for me. Below are my VS Code details.

- Version: 1.9.1
- Commit: f9d0c687ff2ea7aabd85fb9a43129117c0ecf519
- Date: 2017-02-09T00:26:45.394Z
- Shell: 1.4.6
- Renderer: 53.0.2785.143
- Node: 6.5.0

I installed [Nodemon](https://nodemon.io/) globally `npm install -g nodemon` and created VS Code launch configuration as below

```
    {
    "name": "Nodemon Launch Server",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--debug=5858"
    ],
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/server.js",
    "restart": true,
    "port": 5858,
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
   }
```

Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/node-debugging#_restarting-debug-sessions-automatically-when-source-is-edited

Comment: note that `--debug` is deprecated and in my experience can cause app to crash, use `--inspect` instead.

Comment: can I configure it to refresh the page in the browser as well ?

Comment: Following is the content of my launch.json. This solved the issue for me.  
`{ "version": "0.2.0", "configurations": [ { "type": "node", "request": "launch", "name": "Launch Program", "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js", "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon", "restart": true, "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}", "runtimeArgs": ["--inspect=5858"], "port": 5858, "console": "integratedTerminal", "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen" } ] }`

Answer (score 6):

Restarting the debugger automatically after editing our Application files :

Add debugger configuration in  Vscode lunch program  for nodejs like below screen-shot.

[image]

Add two lines in below file path:

.vscode/launch.json

```
"runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
"restart":true
```

Assuming the you have installed **nodemon** globally

```
npm install nodemon -g
```

More information follow the official document link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

Answer (score 5):

You can also install nodemon locally `npm install nodemon --save-dev`.

And the following example of configurations of VS Code launch.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Nodemon",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/server/index.js",
    "restart": true,
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
  }
]
```

Comment: When nodemon restarts after a file change, it throws error that `Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:5858 failed: address already in use`

Comment: It should works the same way as webstruck's method with exception of you need install nodemon locally in your project

Answer (score 1):

Use [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to watch your code and restart automatically

```
npm install pm2 -g
npm install pm2
```

**process.json**

```
{
    name        : "App",
    script      : "app.js",
    watch       : true,
}
```

You can find the demo @
https://github.com/sivasankars/jade-title-rendering

Answer (score 0):

To add to Siva's comments

This would go to the ecosystem.config.js with the new pm2 version

module.exports = {

```
 apps : [{
    **name: 'App',
    script: 'app.js',
    watch: false,**
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }],

  deploy : {
    production : {
      user : 'node',
      host : '212.83.163.1',
      ref  : 'origin/master',
      repo : 'git@github.com:repo.git',
      path : '/var/www/production',
      'post-deploy' : 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production'
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me to run an Express server:

```
{
      "name": "Nodemon Launch Server",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
      "runtimeArgs": [
          "--inspect-brk"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/www",
      "restart": true,
      // "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the Oleksandr's answer didn't work.

Instead of

```
"runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
```

the below should work.

```
"runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",
```

Also note that making sure the node program file should be on the current or project directory, for example, nodemon-ning ./../file.js may not work but nodemon does not restart the program when its file change depending on the nodemon version or the environment. Your script file should be located on e.g. ./file.js