# Changes done in the VS code not reflecting in the Apollo Sandbox in graphQL

Tags: visual-studio-code, graphql, apollo-server, vscode-debugger, vue-apollo

I have been learning graphQL from few days. I am new to it. I've created a GraphQL project in VS code. For running the code I am writing 'node index.js' at first and code runs on Apollo sandbox explorer. But whenever I do any changes in the sourcecode file in VS Code, those are not reflecting on the apollo explorer. I've to Restart the vscode and again rerun it.

Please help how do I see the changes immediately without restarting the VS Code

Comment: You're looking for [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode editor - Restart NodeJs server when file is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248007/vscode-editor-restart-nodejs-server-when-file-is-changed)